# Изменение класса/id элемента через javascript dom или css через css selector div text

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, cssselect

**Предистория**: 
С пользотельской стороны необходимо изменять css элемента в зависимости от того, содержит ли этот самый текст определенный шаблон. Стили меняю через stylish. Уже пытался найти плагин соответствующий, пытался найти в самом css возможности для этого. Но не нашел.

Сейчас думаю о том, что через gracemonkey используя управление dom моделью с помощью javascript - можно изменить/добавить класс/id элемента, что позволит в css добавить необходимые свойства.

**Суть** вопроса заключается в следующем:
У div'а нет id, есть только class. Выбирая

> document.getElementsByClassName("im_message_text")

мы получаем HTML.коллекцию.

**Как** написать:

> если в теле элемента коллекции содержится паттерн А - то изменить класс элемента на Х

?

Заранее благодарен за советы :)

ЗЫ. Выбирая теги увидел css selectors, бегло просмотрел статью на w3schools на эту тему. Ничего не нашел. Посмотрю внимательнее, но если кто знает как с их помощью решить вопросы - был бы весьма признателен!

**UPD**:
Я нашел ответ для jQuery. Он мне не совсем подходит, так как хочу простой JavaScript. Для моего случая выглядит так:

> $('.im_message_text:contains("PROBLEM")').css("color", "red");

Так же в css selectors старых нашел упоминание о :contains. Куда его убрали, и зачем?

Сейчас есть Element[attr*="text"]. Но текст внутри div'а это не атрибут. А это было бы самым крутым решением этого вопроса.

Comment: что мешает пробежаться по полученной коллекции и проверить нужный текст?

Comment: @Grundy , если честно - то незнание как. Можете подсказать? В jQuery я так понимаю именно это и сделано, в качестве обертки. Но я пока не нашел как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как возвращается несколько элементов, то для проверки каждого нужно просто пробежаться по ним. Сделать это можно несколькими способами, например

Обычный цикл

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".im_message_text"); //либо document.getElementsByClassName

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    if(element.innerHTML.indexOf('PROBLEM')>-1){//можно так же проверять innerText, textContent
        element.classList.remove('im_message_text');
        element.classList.add('new-class');
    }
}
```

Либо то же самое с помощью функции forEach

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".im_message_text"),function(element){
    if(element.innerHTML.indexOf('PROBLEM')>-1){//можно так же проверять innerText, textContent
        element.classList.remove('im_message_text');
        element.classList.add('new-class');
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Правда если кто-то даст ответ как это сделать средствами css - уж не серчайте, я буду вынужден поменять "правильный ответ" :)

Comment: @Crystal, на данный момент - никак.